# Listing a model in a drop down menu its submenu

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model named Portfolio. I list all the Portfolios I created on my page in a drop down menu like this:

```
<ul>
  <% @portfolios.each do |portfolio| %>
    <li style="z-index: 2;"><%= link_to portfolio.name, portfolio_path(portfolio) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I have three Portfolios in the drop down menu: Advertising, Graphic Design, Web Development. Then I also have a menu item called Photography which opens up a sub-menu of Portrait, Landscape, and Editorial.  So Advertising, Graphic Design, Web Development, Portrait, Landscape, Editorial are all models of Portfolio.  Photography is just there to facilitate a sub-menu for Portrait, Landscape, and Editorial.  I'm not really sure how to set this up.  Should I create a new model named something like Photography_Portfolio?  And how do I create the Photography menu item if it's not a Portfolio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you storing in the Portfolio model? I would probably just hard code the menu.
Depending on the use case I would hard code the Top level menu items and pull in the different `portfolios` in the drop down menu, you could, for example, create different scopes for the different types.

Comment: A Porfolio has a :name, and has_many :pictures.  A Picture is a model which contains an :image...yes, I don't see why I just don't hard code the menu.  I guess I was trying to do it programmatically...but what do you mean by different scopes?

Comment: I don't know your use case, but if you would like the submenus dynamic so users can add their own ```portfolios``` in a GUI, you could populate the predefined hard coded top menus by fetching the different submenus with [active record scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes), you could also use [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) to diversify them.